# How to? Upside down area plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

A year or so ago I produced a hydrograph figure in Excel. This was fine at the time, but I am now at a stage where I am applying work to multiple cases, and want to easily reproduce my work from R. Therefore I'm looking to recreate this figure (or create something like this) using the graphing functions in R.

I am reasonably familiar with ggplot2, but the difficulty with my hydrograph is introducing the part that is coloured blue - I'm not sure if that is a) possible and if it is, b) how to do this. I believe it is essentially an upside down area plot, overlain on two quite generic and normal plots.

I was hoping somebody might be able to give me some help, either by saying it is possible, or giving me some pointers on how to start. It would be much appreciated!

[image]

```
Year Average Min Max
1953 0.71 0.51 1.02
1954 1.16 0.62 3.54
1955 1.62 0.62 3.54
1956 1.01 0.62 2.78
1957 1.31 0.62 3.79
1958 1.66 0.88 5.07
1959 1.27 0.31 3.82
1960 0.96 0.38 3.79
1961 1.31 0.44 3.65
1962 1.01 0.51 2.53
1963 0.90 0.54 1.89
1964 0.71 0.32 1.64
1965 0.89 0.44 3.40
1966 1.41 0.60 3.79
1967 1.29 0.60 2.83
1968 1.28 0.63 3.79
1969 1.60 0.60 4.16
1970 1.28 0.51 3.31
1971 1.08 0.47 3.51
1972 1.00 0.46 3.63
1973 0.77 0.44 1.75
1974 1.26 0.49 5.86
1975 1.41 0.56 3.37
1976 0.72 0.14 2.22
1977 1.41 0.47 7.00
1978 1.14 0.56 2.48
1979 1.45 0.69 5.56
1980 1.22 0.65 2.94
1981 1.48 0.81 6.71
1982 1.15 0.54 2.91
1983 1.31 0.62 2.75
1984 1.14 0.61 2.81
1985 1.19 0.66 3.98
1986 1.06 0.53 2.40
1987 1.55 0.79 4.16
1988 1.56 0.63 4.94
1989 0.70 0.33 1.48
1990 0.57 0.17 2.16
1991 0.47 0.15 0.92
1992 0.56 0.20 2.89
1993 1.17 0.47 5.84
1994 1.50 0.54 4.25
1995 1.08 0.34 3.15
1996 0.57 0.17 1.36
1997 0.73 0.40 1.49
1998 1.35 0.64 5.81
1999 1.22 0.48 3.47
2000 1.29 0.52 3.96
2001 1.77 0.89 4.74
2002 1.27 0.27 4.20
2003 1.32 0.38 4.33
2004 1.31 0.58 4.91
2005 0.88 0.42 2.02
2006 0.62 0.16 1.69
2007 1.36 0.77 3.00
2008 1.27 0.53 3.66
2009 0.87 0.30 3.32
2010 1.02 0.35 4.37
2011 0.62 0.26 2.88
2012 0.88 0.40 3.93
2013 1.09 0.36 3.84
2014 0.98 0.37 3.62
```

Comment: please edit your question as to include 1. sample data, 2. what you have tried so far, and 3. the specific problem you have.

Comment: I think, you want to have density plots, looks on the ggplot documentation http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_density.html . As @beetroot said, for exact solution, you need to provide data, minimum example.

Comment: Thanks beetroot and @Amit, I have made some changes to my question :)

Comment: this looks like you should be able to solve it with geom_ribbon. You need to create a ymax variable to draw the upper limit (say `DF$ymax  <-  8`) and the you should be able to plot the blue area with `geom_ribbon( aes(x = Year, ymin = Max, ymax = ymax), fill = "lightblue", colour = NA)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `geom_ribbon` for both the lower and the upper filled band.

`geom_ribbon` takes two y arguments, `ymin` and `ymax`. For the upper, `ymin` corresponds to your `Max` for the lower `ymax` corresponds to your `Min`.

```
ggplot(x, aes(x = Year, y = Average))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_ribbon( aes(x = Year, ymin = ymin, ymax = Min), fill = "red")+
  geom_ribbon( aes(x = Year, ymin = Max, ymax = ymax), fill = "lightblue")
```

[image]

Comment: That's absolutely perfect! Thank you so much, I had no idea it would simply be an adaptation of geom_ribbon! Very elegant, cheers